# Need to "refresh" app's screen on button press

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, calayer

I have an app that lets users capture photos. Right now, when a user presses the button to snap a photo, I create a `CALayer` object and set it's contents property to equal the image object that was just created.

So basically, when the user snaps their photo, the captured image is displayed on the screen.

Right now I have a button that is always on the screen. If the user has not taken a photo yet, and they press this button, then it performs a segue and takes them back to the main app screen.

If the user has taken a photo, and they press this button, it pulls up an action sheet and gives them 2 options: "Cancel" and "Delete". If they press "Delete" it segues and takes them back to the main app screen.

I need to make it so that if they press "Delete", it will basically refresh the view controller so that they are still able to capture a brand new picture. I don't want it taking them back to the main app screen.

I just don't know how to "refresh" the view controller. I tried calling `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` but that doesn't do anything. I have a feeling the best bet would be to somehow "kill" or "refresh" the CALayer that was created but I'm not sure if this is the best way or how I would do that.

Also, I am using `AVFoundation` if that makes a difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I am now calling the `setNeedsDisplay` method call on the layer like this and it is working perfectly:

```
[_subLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

Do I need to do anything else, like "refresh" or "kill" the object that holds the image that was just captured, or will `ARC` take care of this?

Comment: How about in viewWillAppear: ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here session is Object of AVCaptureSession

if ([session isRunning]) 
{
        [session stopRunning];
}
[session startRunning];
```

Comment: Would this be better for performance compared to the "UPDATE" solution that I added to the bottom of my original question?